# What is the difference between a modal window and a dialogue window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question describes exactly what i want to know . What is the difference between a modal window and a dialogue. When a modal window becomes a dialogue and vice versa ? How do i go about achieving both ? A nudge in the right direction will be very much appreciated .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A modal window is a windows that runs on top of an application, so that you can't do anything at all with the applciation until you have closed the modal window.

A jQuery dialog is not a separate window, so technically it can't be a modal window. It can however emulate most of what a modal window does, by putting an overlay element over the rest of the page so that you can't interact with it.

Answer (score 3):

A modal window will not let you continue until you close it.

Comment: Does it mean , it can be closed any way. Will it be closed only after clicking on an apparent (x) sign on the top, or even if i click on the escape key ? Which is it ?

Comment: when you show a not modal window like an error message, the user is able to klick on the main window and continue. A modal window will require the user to klick OK or close the window by pressing x or alt f4.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main categories of temporary windows in IxD:
Modless and Modal

**Modless**: that dont require users to exit out to access the behind layers - like tooltip, select, popover (non-sticky), menu etc. These dont have the overlay and you can see all the behind layers as-is.

**Modals**: that require users to take an action before they can access the behind layers - like dialog (a,k,a alert dialog), slide-in-panel, bottom-sheet (new in mobile), popover (skicky). These are mostly required to have the overlay to afford that this is not letting you access the behind layer till you get rid of this.

Visually -- shadows should be reserved for these two in the UI