# Bootstrap - Editing TextArea Behind Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that uses Bootstrap 3. In this page, I need to have a text area that a person can put their answer in. The answer is to a story problem. The story problem appears in a modal dialog. The setup can be seen in this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OWZBWtismc). The code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Answer (<a id="showProblemLink" href="#">view problem</a>)</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="7">      </textarea>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="problemModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
            The local school wants a new playground.
            The lot they can use for the playground is shaped like a rectangle.
            The school has decided to let the students design the new playground.
            The students have decided that they want 1/4 of the playground to be a football field.
              Another 3/8 of the lot will be used for a basketball court.
              How much of the lot is remaining for the slides and swings?
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>        
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

My users want to be able to keep the story problem open in the modal window while they enter their answer. This will let them double-check their answer. The obvious answer is to have them re-open the dialog. But, apparently, this isn't good enough. I really need to keep the dialog open and let the user enter data in the text area behind/under it. Seems weird to me. But, that's what I gotta do.

My problem is, when I click on the `textarea`, the dialog disappears. I tried adding `data-backdrop="false"`. While that kept dialog open, it didn't let me actually edit the `textarea`. What am I missing?

Comment: if the users need it open, why don't you just add a paragraph with the problem? it's much easier I think to drop the modal and rethink the page.

Comment: @Miguel - I agree with your opinion. However, there's a lot more involved in the page. This is just a small part of it. I really do need to find a way to keep the dialog open and edit the `textarea` behind/underneath it.

Comment: well you can try to play with bootstrap modal events like $(document).on('hide.bs.modal', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});
this will prevent that the modal closes, but you have to play with the other elements on your page that I don't know.
in here you can see the the modal events available..hope it helps
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Comment: If the question needs to stay in the dialog and not on the page, how about instead, moving the answer textbox into the modal? Or moving the question to a [popover element](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_popover.asp) rather than dialog.

Comment: You don't want a modal dialog.  The point of a modal dialog is the user must dismiss it before returning to the underlying page/application.  See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12045/what-is-a-modal-dialog-window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is very simple to get **exactly** what you want.

[image]

What you are actually looking for is a **Dialog** and not a Modal.

Here is a [**working example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZbjYj) using jQuery UI Dialog.

---

**Explanation:**

- A modal is designed to block user interaction with the application.
- A [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) looks and acts similar, but is designed to let the user continue interacting with the page (You can set it manually to block everything if you want)

Here is a [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949331/what-is-the-difference-between-a-modal-window-and-a-dialogue-window) about it

---

**Some details about the example:**

By default a dialog is draggable by the header. I kept the example similar to your modal so I took out the header by using:

```
dialogClass: 'dialog-modal'
```

And

```
.dialog-modal .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  display:none;
}
```

To make the whole dialog draggable I used:

```
draggable: false
```

And

```
.parent().draggable();
```

If you actually do want a header, you can delete all these parts. Here is an [example with a header](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpzbPN)

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is, when I click on the textarea, the dialog disappears. I
>   tried adding data-backdrop="false".

It's because you're not actually clicking the textarea, you were clicking an overlay element which would close the modal when clicked.

I'm not sure if removing the overlay element would able you to input on the text area, but even so I don't think that's a good idea(removing the overlay and able you to do something behind while the modal is still up).

So what I suggest is to:
Have a button on the modal when clicked it should show another textarea. And when you input something on the textarea it would update the contents inside the main text area.

**So here's the new modal:**

[image]
[image]

See working [example](http://www.bootply.com/CGLMkcmEoG).

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to achieve is not easily possible.

- Hiding modal background - **easy**
- Moving whole modal div - **medium**
- Making the text area behind the modal take the focus - **very hard**

I understand you want to save space on the page, that's why I would suggest the cleanest option and closest to what you are trying to achieve: [Bootstrap Collapse](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse)

[DEMO here](http://www.bootply.com/Nurj4I8vBs)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions I could think of for this would be to either:

1. move your answer `textarea` to the dialog that has the question in it.
2. or to use a popover instead of a modal.

So [here is my example](http://www.bootply.com/yNkSQxLoW0) of using a popover rather than a modal.

Stackoverflow snippet, which looks terrible because it's missing all the bootstrap styling so check the bootply link:

```js
$(".pop-div > a").popover({
  html: true,
  placement: "left",
  trigger: "click",
  title: function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.pop-title').text()
  },
  content: function() {
    return $(this).siblings('.pop-content').text()
  }
});
```

```css
.pop-div {
  display: inline;
}
.pop-title,
.pop-content {
  display: none;
}
.popover-title {
  font-size: 15px;
}
.popover-content {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Answer (
        <div class="pop-div">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);">view problem</a>
          <div class="pop-title">Question</div>
          <div class="pop-content">
            <p>
              The local school wants a new playground. The lot they can use for the playground is shaped like a rectangle. The school has decided to let the students design the new playground. The students have decided that they want 1/4 of the playground to be a football
              field. Another 3/8 of the lot will be used for a basketball court. How much of the lot is remaining for the slides and swings?
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        )</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="7"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a little fiddling as this is an odd problem, but here's the solution I came up with.

I made a textarea *inside* the modal that is hidden from view and will capture any typing done while the modal is open. When the user closes the modal, focus is sent back to the real textarea.

HTML (slightly modified):

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Answer (<a id="showProblemLink" href="#">view problem</a>)    </label>
      <textarea id="outside-modal" class="form-control" rows="7">          </textarea>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="problemModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
              The local school wants a new playground.
              The lot they can use for the playground is shaped like a rectangle.
              The school has decided to let the students design the new playground.
              The students have decided that they want 1/4 of the playground to be a football field.
              Another 3/8 of the lot will be used for a basketball court.
              How much of the lot is remaining for the slides and swings?
            </p>
            <textarea id="inside-modal"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>        
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>`
```

CSS:

```
textarea#inside-modal {
  position:absolute;
  left:-4000px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#showProblemLink").on("click", function() {
    //show the modal
  $('#problemModal').modal('show');
  //fill the hidden textarea with the real textarea's contents
  $('#problemModal textarea#inside-modal').val($('textarea#outside-modal').val());
  //capture user input in modal and send to outside textarea
  $('#problemModal textarea#inside-modal').on('input',function(e) {
    //fill the outside textarea with the inside textarea's contents
    $('textarea#outside-modal').val($('textarea#inside-modal').val());
  }).focus();
});
//when modal closed, send focus back to textarea
$("#problemModal").on('hidden.bs.modal',function() {
  $('textarea#outside-modal').focus();
});
```

See [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Ub0iqZb4XR)

Comment: Thank you for this attempt. However, I still can't edit the `textarea` while the dialog is open in your example.

Comment: You should be able to just type while the dialog is open and whatever you type will appear in the textarea?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be to use Popover, and on a focus event of the textarea you have a "modal-like" feature.

The benefit to this is that you retain the ability to keep users focused on which textarea belongs to which story as when you remove the overlay you have the potential of losing context of where the modal was needed, or users doing things like opening multiple modals, etc.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Answer (score 0):

I have made a snippet [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ac4g4awy/2/) which can fulfil your need where i have manually input into the `textarea` using `event.key` and `event.keyCode` while the modal is shown.

```js
var $text = $('#textarea');
var backEdit = false;
var $modal = $('#problemModal');
$("#showProblemLink").on("click", function() {
  $modal.modal('show');
});

$modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  backEdit = true;
})
$modal.on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  backEdit = false;
})
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if (backEdit) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    formatTextArea(keyCode);
  }
});

function formatTextArea(keycode) {
  var val = $text.val();
  var caretPos = $text[0].selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = $text.val();
  $text.val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + String.fromCharCode(keycode) + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Answer (<a id="showProblemLink" href="#">view problem</a>)</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="7" id="textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>

  <div id="problemModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>
            The local school wants a new playground. The lot they can use for the playground is shaped like a rectangle. The school has decided to let the students design the new playground. The students have decided that they want 1/4 of the playground to be a football
            field. Another 3/8 of the lot will be used for a basketball court. How much of the lot is remaining for the slides and swings?
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A modal is per definition 'modal' aka **'always on top dialog'**, so all you have to do is to make it non-modal, use your html layout this can be done via jQuery :

```
$('#problemModal').removeClass('modal')
    .hide()
    .css('position','absolute')
    .css('top',0)
    .css('left',(screen.width - $('#problemModal').width())/2);
$("#showProblemLink").on("click", function() {
    $('#problemModal').show();
});

$('#modal-close-btn').click(function(){
    $('#problemModal').hide();
});
```

Here is a working [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/wDd3U6R5ET) as a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can deactivate the modal "force focus" (eg: prevent edition of external textarea) by removing the document event "focusin.modal":

```js
$("#problemModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $(document).off("focusin.modal");
});
```

If you want to keep the cursor focus on the textarea after the modal has been opened just add `$("textarea").focus();`

```js
$("#problemModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
    $(document).off("focusin.modal");
    $("textarea").focus();
});
```